# How to install gems with using jruby-complete.jar

Tags: rubygems, jruby

I'm new to java, please help!

I've put downloaded `jruby-complete-1.7.21.jar` to `/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/activiti-explorer/WEB-INF/lib` and chowned it to `tomcat6:tomcat6` as almost each file in that directory.

When I execute `gem environment`

```
/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/activiti-explorer/WEB-INF/lib# java -jar jruby-complete-1.7.21.jar -S gem environmentRubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.8
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2015-07-07 patchlevel 551) [java]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: file:/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/activiti-explorer/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-complete-1.7.21.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/gems/shared
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: "java -cp :/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/activiti-explorer/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-complete-1.7.21.jar org.jruby.Main"
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: file:/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/activiti-explorer/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-complete-1.7.21.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /root/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: file:/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/activiti-explorer/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-complete-1.7.21.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-java-1.6
  - GEM PATHS:
     - file:/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/activiti-explorer/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-complete-1.7.21.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/gems/shared
     - /root/.gem/jruby/1.9
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "install" => "--no-rdoc --no-ri --env-shebang"
     - "update" => "--no-rdoc --no-ri --env-shebang"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /sbin
     - /bin
```

I see strange path `file:/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/activiti-explorer/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-complete-1.7.21.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/gems/shared`

**Where it's supposed to save gems?**

When I execute `gem install` it complains of permissions

```
root@stage:/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/activiti-explorer/WEB-INF/lib# java -jar jruby-complete-1.7.21.jar -S gem install faraday
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the file:/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/activiti-explorer/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-complete-1.7.21.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/gems/shared directory.
```

**UPDATE1:**

If I try to install the gem as user tomcat6, I get another error:

```
tomcat6@stage:/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/activiti-explorer/WEB-INF/lib$  java -jar jruby-complete-1.7.21.jar -S gem install faraday
Fetching: multipart-post-2.0.0.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::ENOENT)
    No such file or directory - /usr/share/tomcat6/.gem/jruby/1.9/cache/multipart-post-2.0.0.gem
```

Answer (score 4):

As the tomcat user you can see what the default gem path is set to on the file system:

java -jar jruby-complete-1.7.21.jar -S gem env

You can specify where to install the gem on the system: 
java -jar jruby-complete-1.7.21.jar -S gem install -i /path/to/location faraday

You can set the GEM_PATH environment variable to point to that location.

You can also look into using rvm to manage ruby, and jruby versions as well as the gem directory using gemdir.